# VSCode, how do you import a function that is in another file? I get an ImportError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, importerror

I have 2 files: print.py and cool.py. They are in the same map.

print.py:

```
def test():
    print('cool')
```

cool.py:

```
from print import test

test()
```

I get error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from 'print' (c:\Users\me\OneDrive\Creative Cloud Files\Dokument\Projects\project1\print.py)`

Why am I getting an error here? If I write import & they are in the same map, shouldn't I be able to use the functions in a different file?

Comment: Since `print` is a reserved, built-in word, I'd think that'd break things. You should try using a unique name instead.

Comment: You should try and rename print.py to something which does not use a name already used in python.

Comment: The name `print` shouldn't be an issue here since it isn't reserved (although it's certainly not good practice to potentially shadow the built-in with a module name). Is the code that you have here exactly what you have in your real code, and are you sure that they're in the same directory?

Comment: I changed the names & it still doesn't work 

Comment: Ya, the name won't have any bearing here. I tested it an `print` works fine as a module name (at least in Python 3). Try changing the import to just `import print`, then do `print(dir(print))`. What do you get?

Comment: ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']

Comment: So, you appear to be looking at the wrong file, or `print.py` never saved correctly. Make sure that your `print.py` is correctly saved into the folder that you expect (double check with an external editor), and restart your IDE if necessary.

Comment: Fixed it by running the imported file beforehand. After creating print.py I never ran it since I didn't doubt what it did. Apparently vscode doesn't really recognize the file unless I run it once before.